# Assign classes to all the td of a table from an Object using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to assign classes from a given javascript object to all the td of a table but I am unable to achieve that, this is what I have I tried. I am looping through all tds and in another, I am looping through the json.and for some reason, I can't add ids to any of the element.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <table id="vapEaseSegmentsTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> </th>
          <th>Convert</th>
          <th>Maintain</th>
          <th>Engage</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Email Engaged</th>
          <td>0.4%</td>
          <td>3.4%</td>
          <td>6.4%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Email Inactive</th>
          <td>5.0%</td>
          <td>4.4%</td>
          <td>7.4%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Likely to Thrive</th>
          <td>8.0%</td>
          <td>7.4%</td>
          <td>8.4%</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

JQUERY

```
  var easeSegmentNameMap = {
   "EMAIL_ENGAGED": {
     CONVERT: "highestValue",
     MAINTAIN: "mediumValue",
     ENGAGE: "lowValue"
   },
   "EMAIL_INACTIVE": {
     CONVERT: "mediumValue",
     MAINTAIN: "highestValue",
     ENGAGE: "lowValue"
   },
   "LIKELY_TO_THRIVE": {
     CONVERT: "highestValue",
     MAINTAIN: "lowValue",
     ENGAGE: "mediumValue"
   }
 }

 function setClass() {
  $("td").each(function(index, value) {

     $.each(easeSegmentNameMap, function(index, easeSegmentName) {
     $(this).addClass("add class from easeSegmentNameMap in sequence ");
   });

   });



 }
 setClass();
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/emozsaurab/m94dsaLb/28/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use **jQuery parent > child Selector** to select all td.

```
$("#vapEaseSegmentsTable td").addClass("red");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're changing the `this` context by entering the second `each()`.

Approach 1 - store an outer reference to the `td` so you can access it from within the second `each()` callback:

```
$("td").each(function(index, value) {
    let td = $(this);
    $.each(easeSegmentNameMap, function(index, easeSegmentName) {
        td.addClass("add class from easeSegmentNameMap in sequence ");
    });
});
```

Approach 2 - run the second `each()` callback in the context of the `td`:

```
$("td").each(function(index, value) {
    $.each(easeSegmentNameMap, function(index, easeSegmentName) {
        $(this).addClass("add class from easeSegmentNameMap in sequence ");
    }.bind(this));
});
```

However, if you're adding the same classes to each and every `td`, this is woefully inefficient. Instead it would be better to loop at the top level over the object, then apply classes that way.

```
let tds = $('td');
$.each(easeSegmentNameMap, function(index, easeSegmentName) {
    tds.addClass("add class from easeSegmentNameMap in sequence ");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For non-jQuery solution you can use [querySelectorAll()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) which matches a specified CSS selector. Then add the class via [classList.add()](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp).As for id you can use [el.id](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp) = new_id to do so.The code should look like this :

```
    function addClassAndId(){
        var els = document.querySelectorAll("#vapEaseSegmentsTable td");
        var len = els.length;
        for(var i = 0, var len = els.length; i < len ; i++){
            els[i].classList.add("test"); //To add class on top of existing ones
            els[i].id = "td_"+i; // Set the id to td_n where n is the number of the td
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm able to add the classes by modifying your code like this:

```
var easeSegmentNameMap = {
   "EMAIL_ENGAGED": {
     CONVERT: "highestValue",
     MAINTAIN: "mediumValue",
     ENGAGE: "lowValue"
   },
   "EMAIL_INACTIVE": {
     CONVERT: "mediumValue",
     MAINTAIN: "highestValue",
     ENGAGE: "lowValue"
   },
   "LIKELY_TO_THRIVE": {
     CONVERT: "highestValue",
     MAINTAIN: "lowValue",
     ENGAGE: "mediumValue"
   }
 }

 setClass();

 function setClass() {
  $("td").each(function(index, value) {

     $.each(easeSegmentNameMap, function(easeIndex, easeSegmentName) {
     $(value).addClass("add class from easeSegmentNameMap in sequence ");

   });

   });
 }
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rojasjo/a7c3fwr8/42/)